# How best to design SSIS packages for multiple table loads

Tags: design, ssis

This is a question about SSIS package design.

We have an SSIS package built in VS 2008 that loads ~ 22 tables from as many fixed width files into a data warehouse. Each file has its own data flow task. All of the data flow tasks are inside a single control flow.

Would it be better to create a separate package for each table? Does the current design sound acceptable?

The package control flow appears cluttered to me, and it can take a minute or two for data validation to complete after opening the package. Correcting a problem with a single data flow means working in a package that also has all the other data flows. I'm wondering if separating it out into individual packages would make for better maintainability and readability. But, I don't know if doing that would cause any other issues. I guess I could use guidance.

Comment: it would be better not to use ssis

Comment: @Ewan I don't have much choice in the matter